# How to populate POST data from postProcess to smarty tpl via hookPaymentReturn

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to change the behavior of a payment module in Prestashop 1.6.x, in order to **create a customer receipt** from the approval source to **the order confirmation page**.

I would like a suggestion concerning the best method and some guidance to achieve it a the correct way.

More specifically, when the user completes the transaction using a specific payment module, I need to **populate the order confirmation page with POST data from the external banking source** which is available in the `postProcess()` function, in order to **use it as a kind of receipt**.

As far as I can understand, after payment has been made:

1. the module validates the order and elaborates the external source's POST data through a `PostProcess()` function (part of an extended `ModuleFrontController` class) and found in a controllers/front/validation.php file.
2. Within `PostProcess()`, if external data is OK (i.e. transaction approved), it redirects to the order confirmation controller with the following:

```
public function postProcess() {

(...)

$somePostData = '';

//this is the variable that is populated from POST data and i need to show in the confirmation.tpl
$somePostData = Tools::getValue('postdata'); 

Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart=' .
                    $this->context->cart->id . '&id_module=' .
                    $this->module->id . '&id_order=' .
                    $this->module->currentOrder . '&key=' .
                    $customer->secure_key
                );

(...)

}
```

3. At some point `hookPaymentReturn()` is being called (resided in the main module php file), which loads a specific module template file related to the order confirmation page.
4. In order to show some variables through the tpl file, the only solution i've found is to use a **smarty variable** just before returning the populated tpl as shown below:

```
public function hookPaymentReturn()
    {
        if (!$this->active) {
            return;
        }

        //this is the variable that I want to populate from the above-mentioned $somePostData found in postProcess()
        $receipt_display = 'some data';

        $this->context->smarty->assign('receipt_display', $receipt_display);

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/confirmation.tpl');
    }
```

So my question is how can I populate $receipt_display with data from $somePostData as shown in the two above-mentioned code sections?

Is there a different methodology that you could suggest if the above-mentioned is wrong?

Thank you,
mmystery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if $_POST['somePostData'] is just a simple string, if so, add it to `Tools::redirect` as next param in URL, if this is most complex data you have two options which i see:

1. create some table with simple mapping: ps_yourpaymentmethod_data: id_order | data and get data by id in `hookPaymentReturn`
2. set value in cookie:

$this->context->cookie->someVar = Tools::getValue('postData');
$this->context->cookie->write();

read it in `hookPaymentReturn`:

```
if ($this->context->cookie->someVar) {
    $someVar = $this->context->cookie->someVar;
    $this->context->cookie->someVar = null;
    $this->context->cookie->write();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Krystian. The data to be transferred is complex and include transaction data, so it is not feasable the url. So the options are either to write to the database or to set the variable to a cookie. Is there an option to set this data also in a php session variable? Is it a good idea?

Comment: i think that you should save this data to db if those are important informations about transaction, for example transaction id etc. it could be useful in case of any returns etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, Krystian! I chose the option of the temporary cookie as this information should not be saved to the db.